# Multiple Contexts For Request Scope?

Tags: tomcat7, jersey-2.0, weld

I am attempting to use Weld with Tomcat7 and Jersey, and in my log files I am seeing this:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-001304: More than one context active for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

The application deploys properly and I only see this when attempting to hit on my Jersey endpoints.

Here is the pertinent parts of the pom.xml

> ```
>   <!-- Jersey Deps -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
>         </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
>     </dependency>
> ```

```
    <!-- CDI Deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

And here's my "MainApplication" that extends ResourceConfig:

```
public class MainApplication extends ResourceConfig {
public MainApplication() {
    packages(true, "com.example.api");
    property(ServerProperties.BV_SEND_ERROR_IN_RESPONSE, true);
    property(ServerProperties.BV_DISABLE_VALIDATE_ON_EXECUTABLE_OVERRIDE_CHECK, true);
}
}
```

Here's my web.xml (the servlet section):

```
    <servlet>
<servlet-name>Jersey Servlet Container</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
<param-value>net.di2e.isfr.foldr.MainApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Jersey Servlet Container</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I am uber-confsued what could be going wrong.